# Ergonomic Mac keyboards

Tags: keyboard

I could really use a good ergonomic keyboard for my iMac to try to deal with some wrist issues. The reviews of the Kinesis Freestyle 2 seem basically OK, but there are some complaints about oddly placed keys and the way the function key works, neither of which really appeals to me.

Does anyone out there have this keyboard? Any comments on this or any other issue? Also, are there other ergo keyboards I should be looking at? (The Kinesis Advantage doesn't really appeal to me, with the placement of common keys in the middle).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is primarily a shopping question.

Comment: Tbh most papers I've seen on the topic suggest that ergonomic keyboards give little to no health improvement but are a pain in the ass to learn to use normally. The spacing between your keyboard and the desk's edge, higher of your chair/keyboard, etc. have a much more substantial health impact than some gimmicky "ergonomic keyboard"

Answer (score 1):

As someone who many years ago suffered from a severe case of RSI I suggest that if you are having a problem that you take every ergonomic keyboard out there and throw them into the nearest lake or river. Ergonomic keyboards look good but tend to fix nothing.

Almost all problems causing pain can be fixed by altering your seating, arm position, keyboard location and typing practice.

Your first step should be to find a good specialist centre that can analyse all of these things and do such steps as wire up your muscles and see which ones are straining when you type and then retrain you. If you need such things as wrist supports or angled keyboards they will tell you so and almost certainly advise on which ones would best suit you. If they don't then they are not the best place for you and find somewhere else.

If you are having problems see a good specialist centre now, do not wait, do not think that anything you do will fix the problem or that it will go away.

I did not take this advice and ended up spending three months unable to touch a keyboard.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking! (as per my comment above)